# Deserialiazing Json dictionary to list

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a Json file, with the object serialized correctly, but the problem is that the json has what seems like a dictionary with keys that are strings "0","1" and so on.

Is there any way, not involving writing an own parser, to correctly deserialise these into a list?

```
"WeaponSlots":{
        "0":{
           "WeaponInstalled":null,
           "AllowedWeaponTypes":{
              "0":{
                 "0":2
              }
           },
           "AllowedWeapons":null
        },
        "1":{
           "WeaponInstalled":null,
           "AllowedWeaponTypes":{
              "0":{
                 "0":2
              }
           },
           "AllowedWeapons":null
        }
```

Example file: https://pastebin.com/i3LQ3L7j

Comment: Try [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: What *created* this JSON? Can you fix it to make WeaponSlots a proper list?

Comment: You can generate a set of matching C# classes with **https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs** and then use Json.NET to parse it into those types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datatype `Dictionary<string, object>` to deserialize this..

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // load the file.
    var file = File.ReadAllText("Example.json");

    // to generate the 'Example' classes from JSON I used
    // https://app.quicktype.io and changed the name to 'Example'
    var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(file);

    // select the value of each dictionary entry into a list.
    var sections = example.Sections.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```